# Is there a better way to run a command N times in bash?

Tags: bash, loops

I occasionally run a bash command line like this:

```
n=0; while [[ $n -lt 10 ]]; do some_command; n=$((n+1)); done
```

To run `some_command` a number of times in a row -- 10 times in this case.

Often `some_command` is really a chain of commands or a pipeline.

Is there a more concise way to do this?

Comment: Besides the other nice answers, you can use `let ++n` instead of `n=$((n+1))` (3 less characters).

Comment: Some indications of which of these methods are portable would be nice.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/273238/how-to-run-a-command-multiple-times

Comment: I think POSIX requires `n=$(($n+1))`, `n` without `$` is a bash extension.

Comment: If you're willing to change shells, `zsh` has `repeat 10 do some_command; done`.

Comment: on Ubuntu, OP's loop syntax erred for me. had to use `n=0; while [ $n -lt 3 ]; do some_command; n=$((n+1)); done`

Comment: @JohnVandivier I just tried it in bash in a fresh 18.04 docker container, the original syntax as posted in my question still works. Maybe you're running a shell other than bash, like /bin/sh, which is really dash, in which case I get back `sh: 1: [[: not found`.

Comment: yep you nailed it. i was referring to /bin/sh incorrectly...TIL that's called dash!

Answer (score 768, accepted):

If your range has a variable, [use `seq`](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/460600/17671), like this:

```
count=10
for i in $(seq $count); do
    command
done
```

Simply:

```
for run in {1..10}; do
  command
done
```

Or as a one-liner, for those that want to copy and paste easily:

```
for run in {1..10}; do command; done
```

Comment: If you have LOTS of iterations, the form with `for (n=0;n<k;n++))` may be better; I suspect `{1..k}` will materialize a string with all those integers separated by spaces.

Comment: @Joe Koberg, thanks for the tip. I'm typically use N<100 so this seems good.

Comment: Accepting this as the answer since it is slightly more concise (by a whisker) than `for(())`.

Comment: @bstpierre: The brace expansion form can't use variables (easily) to specify the range in Bash.

Comment: That is true. Brace expansion is performed before variable expansion according to http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion , thus it will never see the values of any variables.

Comment: @Dennis Williamson - Thanks for the warning, and for your answer below. 99% of the time I won't need to worry about it.

Comment: Sad thing about variable expansion.
I am using following to loop n-times and have formated numbers:
 `n=15;for i in $(seq -f "%02g" ${n});do echo $i; done
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
13
14
15`

Comment: Ali Omary's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26898191/1727807) is the only one which doesn't use an external tool or have possible side effects, since '_' should never be used to store persistent data. Using `run` as your variable will result in `run` being set after the `for` loop. If you're in a function, you can also use `local run` before the loop to avoid overwriting a variable which may be set outside the function.

Comment: I am using a Mac and CTRL-C won't be able to stop it... only one execution is stopped and it will keep running the loop

Answer (score 242):

Using a constant:

```
for ((n=0;n<10;n++)); do
    some_command; 
done
```

Using a variable (can include math expressions):

```
x=10; for ((n=0; n < (x / 2); n++)); do some_command; done
```

Comment: This is the closest way to programming language ^^ - should be the accepted one!

Comment: This one is better because it's a single line and therefore easier to use within terminal

Comment: You can also use a variable, e.g. `x=10` `for ((n=0; n < $x; n++));`

Comment: @Kunok It's just as acceptable to run the accepted answer in one line: `for run in {1..10}; do echo "on run $run"; done`

Comment: what if  `n` is already set to a specific value? `for (( ; n<10; n++ ))` doesnt work / edit: best probably use one of the other answers like the `while (( n++...` one

Answer (score 167):

Another simple way to hack it:

```
seq 20 | xargs -Iz echo "Hi there"
```

run echo 20 times.

---

Notice that `seq 20 | xargs -Iz echo "Hi there z"` would output:

> Hi there 1
>   Hi there 2
>   ...

Comment: version 2015: `seq 20 | xargs -I{} echo "Hi there {}"`

Comment: Note that `z` is not a good placeholder because it's so common that can be a regular text in command text. Use `{}` will be better.

Comment: Any way to discard the number from `seq` ? so it would just print `Hi there`  20 times (no number)?   EDIT: just use `-I{}` and then do not have any `{}` in the command

Comment: Just use something, you are sure it will not be in the output, for example `IIIII` then it looks nice for example: `seq 20 | xargs -IIIIII timeout 10 yourCommandThatHangs`

Answer (score 158):

If you're using the zsh shell:

```
repeat 10 { echo 'Hello' }
```

Where 10 is the number of times the command will be repeated.

Comment: While it is not an answer to the question (since it explicitly mentions bash), it is very useful and helped me to solve my problem. +1

Comment: Also, if you just typed it in terminal, you could use something like `repeat 10 { !! }`

Comment: Is there any way to get the run number in the block? e.g. `{ echo "Run number $n" }`

Answer (score 36):

Using GNU Parallel you can do:

```
parallel some_command ::: {1..1000}
```

If you do not want the number as argument and only run a single job at a time:

```
parallel -j1 -N0 some_command ::: {1..1000}
```

Watch the intro video for a quick introduction:
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial (http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html). You command line
with love you for it.

Comment: Why would you use a tool whose very reason for existence, as manifestly proven by its name, is to run things *in parallel*, and then give it cryptic argments `-j1 -N0` that *turn off the parallelism*????

Comment: @RossPresser That is a very reasonable question. The reason is that it may be easier to express what you want to do using the GNU Parallel syntax. Think: How would you run `some_command` 1000 times in serial with no arguments? And: Can you express that shorter than `parallel -j1 -N0 some_command ::: {1..1000}`?

Comment: Well, I guess you have sort of a point, but it still really feels like using a finely crafted engine block as a hammer. If I was sufficiently motivated, *and* felt considerate of my future successors trying to understand what I did, I'd probably wrap the confusion in a shell script and just call it with `repeat.sh repeatcount some_command`. For implementation in the shell script I might use `parallel`, if it was already installed on the machine (probably wouldn't be). Or I might gravitate towards xargs since that seems to be fastest when no redirection is needed by `some_command`.

Comment: I apologize if my "very reasonable question" was expressed in an unreasonable manner.

Comment: In this specific case it may not be quite so obvious. It becomes more obvious if you use more options of GNU Parallel, e.g if you want to retry failed commands 4 times and save the output to different files: `parallel -N0 -j1 --retries 4 --results outputdir/ some_command`

Comment: OK, you've made the argument persuasive. I won't say I'm a `parallel` convert yet, but I may look it over this weekend.

Comment: I highly recommend you follow the "Reader's guide" in `man parallel`. It should get you going in less than 15 minutes.

Answer (score 23):

A simple function in the bash config file (`~/.bashrc` often) could work well.

```
function runx() {
  for ((n=0;n<$1;n++))
    do ${*:2}
  done
}
```

Call it like this.

```
$ runx 3 echo 'Hello world'
Hello world
Hello world
Hello world
```

Comment: Like it.  Now if it could be cancelled with ctrl+c, that would be great

Comment: Why using this way to echo $RANDOM n times displays same number?

Comment: This works perfectly. The only thing I needed to change was instead of just doing `do ${*:2}` I added eval `do eval ${*:2}` to make sure that it would work for running commands which don't start with executables. For example, if you want to set an environment variable before running a command like `SOME_ENV=test echo 'test'`.

Comment: here is a version that runs N times or until the first non zero exit code. it can be stopped with ctrl+c

    function runx() {
      success=0
    
      for ((n=0;n<$1 && success==0;n++))
      do 
        ${*:2}
        success=$?
      done
    }

Answer (score 17):

```
for _ in {1..10}; do command; done
```

Note the underscore instead of using a variable.

Comment: Though technically, `_` is a variable name.

Comment: Yeah, why not just use `i` instead of `_`, which can mean the result of the previous command. You can also get the iteration number like `for i in {1..10}; do echo "Run $i"; done`.

Comment: `_` is commonly used as a variable name, when the variable itself is not used later in the code, like in this example here.

Answer (score 15):

If you are OK doing it periodically, you could run the following command to run it every 1 sec indefinitely. You can put other custom checks in place to run it n number of times.

`watch -n 1 some_command`

If you wish to have visual confirmation of changes, append `--differences` prior to the `ls` command.

According to the OSX man page, there's also

> The --cumulative option makes highlighting "sticky", presenting a
>   running display of  all  positions  that  have  ever changed.  The -t
>   or --no-title option turns off the header showing the interval,
>   command, and current time at the top of the display, as well as the
>   following blank line.

Linux/Unix man page can be found [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/watch)

Answer (score 14):

Another form of your example:

```
n=0; while (( n++ < 10 )); do some_command; done
```

Answer (score 13):

`xargs` is **fast**:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
echo "while loop:"
n=0; time while (( n++ < 10000 )); do /usr/bin/true ; done

echo -e "\nfor loop:"
time for ((n=0;n<10000;n++)); do /usr/bin/true ; done

echo -e "\nseq,xargs:"
time seq 10000 | xargs -I{} -P1 -n1 /usr/bin/true

echo -e "\nyes,xargs:"
time yes x | head -n10000 |  xargs -I{} -P1 -n1 /usr/bin/true

echo -e "\nparallel:"
time parallel --will-cite -j1 -N0 /usr/bin/true ::: {1..10000}
```

On a modern 64-bit Linux, gives:

```
while loop:

real    0m2.282s
user    0m0.177s
sys     0m0.413s

for loop:

real    0m2.559s
user    0m0.393s
sys     0m0.500s

seq,xargs:

real    0m1.728s
user    0m0.013s
sys     0m0.217s

yes,xargs:

real    0m1.723s
user    0m0.013s
sys     0m0.223s

parallel:

real    0m26.271s
user    0m4.943s
sys     0m3.533s
```

This makes sense, as the `xargs` command is a single native process that spawns the `/usr/bin/true` command multiple time, instead of the `for` and `while` loops that are all interpreted in Bash. Of course this only works for a single command; if you need to do multiple commands in each iteration the loop, it will be just as fast, or maybe faster, than passing `sh -c 'command1; command2; ...'` to xargs

The `-P1` could also be changed to, say, `-P8` to spawn 8 processes in parallel to get another big boost in speed.

I don't know why GNU parallel is so slow. I would have thought it would be comparable to xargs.

Comment: GNU Parallel does quite a lot of setup and bookkeeping: It supports programmable replacement strings, it buffers output so output from two parallel jobs are never mixed, it supports direction (You cannot do: xargs "echo >foo") and since it is not written in bash it has to spawn a new shell to do the redirection. The primary cause, however, is in the Perl module IPC::open3 - so any work on getting that faster will result in a faster GNU Parallel.

Answer (score 8):

For one, you can wrap it up in a function:

```
function manytimes {
    n=0
    times=$1
    shift
    while [[ $n -lt $times ]]; do
        $@
        n=$((n+1))
    done
}
```

Call it like:

```
$ manytimes 3 echo "test" | tr 'e' 'E'
tEst
tEst
tEst
```

Comment: This will not work if the command to run is more complex than a simple command with no redirections.

Comment: You can make it work for more complex cases, but you may have to wrap the command in a function or script.

Comment: The `tr` here is misleading and it's working on output of `manytimes`, not `echo`. I think you should remove it from sample.

Answer (score 7):

xargs and seq will help

```bsh
function __run_times { seq 1 $1| { shift; xargs -i -- "$@"; } }
```

the view :

```
abon@abon:~$ __run_times 3  echo hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
```

Comment: what does the shift and the double-dash in the command do? Is the 'shift' really necessary?

Comment: This will not work if the command is more complex than a simple command with no redirections.

Comment: Very slow, echo $RANDOM 50 times took 7 sec, and even so it displays same random number each run...

Answer (score 5):

All of the existing answers appear to require [`bash`](http://ports.su/shells/bash), and don't work with a standard BSD UNIX `/bin/sh` (e.g., [`ksh` on OpenBSD](http://bxr.su/o/bin/ksh)).

The below code should work on any BSD:

```
$ echo {1..4}
{1..4}
$ seq 4
sh: seq: not found
$ for i in $(jot 4); do echo e$i; done
e1
e2
e3
e4
$
```

Answer (score 5):

I solved with this loop, where *repeat* is an integer that represents the loops's number

```
repeat=10
for n in $(seq $repeat); 
    do
        command1
        command2
    done
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use this command to repeat your command 10 times or more

```
for i in {1..10}; do **your command**; done
```

for example

```
for i in {1..10}; do **speedtest**; done
```

Answer (score 4):

Yet another answer: Use parameter expansion on empty parameters:

```
# calls curl 4 times 
curl -s -w "\n" -X GET "http:{,,,}//www.google.com"
```

Tested on Centos 7 and MacOS.

Comment: This is interesting, can you provide some more details on why this works?

Comment: It's running the parameter expansion n times but since the parameter is empty it doesn't actually change what is run

Comment: Searching for parameter expansion and curl has led to no results. I barely know curl. It would be awesome if you could point me to some article or perhaps another common name for this feature. Thanks.

Comment: I think this may help https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Answer (score 2):

For loops are probably the right way to do it, but here is a fun alternative:

`echo -e {1..10}"\n" |xargs -n1 some_command`

If you need the iteration number as a parameter for your invocation, use:

`echo -e {1..10}"\n" |xargs -I@ echo now I am running iteration @`

**Edit:** It was rightly commented that the solution given above would work smoothly only with simple command runs (no pipes, etc.). you can always use a `sh -c` to do more complicated stuff, but not worth it.

Another method I use typically is the following function:

`` rep() { s=$1;shift;e=$1;shift; for x in `seq $s $e`; do c=${@//@/$x};sh -c "$c"; done;} ``

now you can call it as:

`rep 3 10 echo iteration @`

The first two numbers give the range. The `@` will get translated to the iteration number. Now you can use this with pipes too:

`rep 1 10 "ls R@/|wc -l"`

with give you the number of files in directories R1 .. R10.

Comment: This will not work if the command is more complex than a simple command with no redirections.

Comment: fair enough, but see my edit above. The edited method uses a sh -c, so should work with redirection too.

Comment: `rep 1 2 touch "foo @"` will not create two files "foo 1" and "foo 2"; rather it creates three files "foo", "1", and "2". There may be a way to get the quoting right using `printf` and `%q`, but it's going to be tricky to get an arbitrary sequence of words correctly quoted into a single string to pass to `sh -c`.

Comment: OP asked for more **concise**, so why are you adding something like this, when there are already 5 more concise answers?

Comment: Once you define the definition of `rep` in your `.bashrc`, further invocations become a lot more concise.

Comment: Beware, though, that `rep` as defined above will take up the standard input for iteration, for no good reason. Why not just use a simple `for` loop like `for ((x=$s; x<=$e; ++x)); do ...; done`?

Answer (score 2):

The script file

```
bash-3.2$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo "The argument is  arg: $1"

for ((n=0;n<$1;n++));
do
  echo "Hi"
done
```

and the output below

```
bash-3.2$  ./test.sh 3
The argument is  arg: 3
Hi
Hi
Hi
bash-3.2$
```

Answer (score 2):

A little bit naive but this is what I usually remember off the top of my head:

```
for i in 1 2 3; do
  some commands
done
```

Very similar to @joe-koberg's answer. His is better especially if you need many repetitions, just harder for me to remember other syntax because in last years I'm not using `bash` a lot. I mean not for scripting at least.

Answer (score 1):

Though many variations have been presented, one interesting edge case not yet addressed--that still falls within the purview of the original question--involves storing the result of each iteration into a separate file, indexed by the current iteration number.

One concise way to do this leverages both `seq` and `xargs` that have already been discussed:

```
seq 10 | xargs -I{} sh -c 'echo hello{} > file{}.txt'
```

That will generate 10 files as follows:

| Filename | Contents |
| --- | --- |
| file1.txt | hello1 |
| file2.txt | hello2 |
| file3.txt | hello3 |
| etc... |  |

And to make it more convenient one can wrap it in a shell function for your .zshrc (or equivalent):

```
loop() {
    count=$1
    command=$2
    seq $count | xargs -I{} sh -c "$command"
}
```

Finally, from the command line one could then just say, e.g.,

```
loop 5 'echo hello{} > file{}.txt'
```

Of course, if one is iterating 10 or more times, then you get non-ordered file names (because, for example, lexicographically, `file10.txt` comes between `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` )!

To fix that, let's use brace expansion instead of `seq`. I find brace expansion wonderfully user friendly, as you just need to provide the "size" of the needed zero-fill in the smaller number, in this case just one zero for single-digit values. So this generates file names `file01.txt`, `file02.txt`, ... `file11.txt`, which is to say, every file will have a 2-digit sequence number!

```
echo {01..11} | xargs -I{} -n1 sh -c 'echo hello{} > file{}.txt'
```

Revising the shell function is slightly more involved:

```
loop() {
    count=$1
    command=$2
    eval "echo {01..$count}" | xargs -I{} -n1 sh -c "$command"
}
```

I have hard-coded that to max out at 99 iterations, which is fine for my needs, but you could adjust for your own.

Answer (score -1):

How about the alternate form of `for` mentioned in [(bashref)Looping Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs)?

Comment: throw him a bone and give an example of the alternate form?