# Run a command N number of times

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Without doing a `for` loop in bash is there a way to execute a command N times? For example:

```
$ pulldown 123 && pulldown 123 && # ...etc [100 times]
```

Comment: Why don't you want to do a loop?  That is the normal way to do something like this.

Comment: Your example is actually different to a for loop, `&&` will break the chain if a command has a non zero return. Is this what you actually want? I.e. a for loop that breaks on error

Comment: Use a `while` loop. Possible duplicate of [Is there a better way to run a command N times in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3737740/608639)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a for loop and simply ignore the argument:

```
for i in $(seq 1 100); do pulldown 123; done
```

If you absolutely can't use a for loop for some reason, you could use `xargs -n 1` and ignore the argument, with something like the following; the `-n 1` indicates to run the command once per line of input, and the `-I XXX` means replace all occurrences of XXX in the command with the current input line (but since we don't use that in the command, it is ignored):

```
seq 1 100 | xargs -n 1 -I XXX pulldown 123
```

Answer (score 4):

A `while` loop could be used, something like this:

```
i=0
while [ $i -lt 100 ]; do
        echo $i
        i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

Alternatively, [ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/) could possibly be used with the -e switch, like this:

```
$ ruby -e '100.times { |i| puts i }'
```