# Running the same test multiple times in Protractor

Tags: protractor

How can we run the same test multiple times in Protractor?

Looks like this has been a problem before, any solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?  Can you give an example

Comment: Under Conf.js I have a Specs: ['test1.js],  If I run > protractor conf.js form the Command Prompt my test runs and I can see the result.                            I like for the  Specs:['test1.js] run 100 times and verify the results.

Answer (score 3):

Solve it on a higher level with bash running protractor from the command line N times:

- [Is there a better way to run a command N times in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737740/is-there-a-better-way-to-run-a-command-n-times-in-bash)

Or, you can also do it via the `grunt` task manager, sample can be found here:

- [Running grunt task multiple times until it fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960934/running-grunt-task-multiple-times-until-it-fails)

---

There is also [`protactor-flake` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-flake) that will automatically rerun failing protractor tests.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what @alecxe suggested, I do this in the bash shell to run protractor n times to find tests that fail intermittently:

`for ((n=0;n<100;n++)); do protractor protractor.conf.js; done`

I use [jasmine-spec-reporter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-spec-reporter), and often add a grep at the end to find only the errors:

`for ((n=0;n<10;n++)); do protractor ./protractor/protractor.conf.js; done | grep FAILED`

Answer (score -1):

Doing a for loop, like in Linux, didn't work for me. What worked for me was this command:

for /l %A in (1, 1, 100) do protractor conf.js %A

/l means we use it for numbers. %A means it's a command line (%%A is used for a batch file)