# Running grunt task multiple times until it fails

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, protractor

What is the canonical way to run the same grunt task continuously, multiple times until it fails?

---

I'd like to keep the question generic, but here is a specific use case:

We have a huge set of end-to-end tests written in Protractor which we run via `grunt` with the help of [`grunt-protractor-runner`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-protractor-runner) and [`grunt-contrib-connect`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-connect). What we'd like to do is to keep the `connect` task running (the web-server serving from a `dist` directory) while looping over the `protractor` until it fails (or/and up to `N` times). The tasks:

```
connect: {
    test: {
        options: {
            base: 'dist',
            port: 9001
        }
    },
},

protractor: {
    options: {
        keepAlive: true,
        noColor: false
    },
    local: {
        options: {
            configFile: "test/e2e/config/local.conf.js"
        }
    }
},

grunt.registerTask('e2e:local', [
    'connect:test',
    'protractor:local'
]);
```

Here, we'd like to execute `connect:test` once and `protractor:local` multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to be as simple as adding the same task to the array of tasks N times (still not sure if we can somehow avoid specifying the `N` and run the task indefinitely until it fails) and, since, by default `grunt` works in the "fail-fast" mode, the whole task would fail on the first fail. In our case:

```
grunt.registerTask('e2e:local', function () {
    var tasks = ['connect:test'];

    var N = 100;
    for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        tasks.push('protractor:local')
    }

    grunt.task.run(tasks);
});
```

`N` here is hardcoded inside the task, but could be passed "from outside" as a [grunt option](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.option).

Comment: I think it's wise to still have `n`, allows you to set a threshold for the process to operate in by design