# Running repetitive commands in terminal

Tags: python, bash, shell, command-line, terminal

I am somewhat new to running shell commands.
Currently I am executing these one at a time in terminal like this:

```
python dna.py databases/small.csv sequences/1.txt
// result

python dna.py databases/small.csv sequences/2.txt
// result

python dna.py databases/small.csv sequences/3.txt
// result

etc...
```

Is there a way to put all these commands in a ***text file*** and run a single command that will execute them all at once?  Lastly, I'd like to pipe this to a results.txt file.

Comment: `bash ./my_text_file_with_python_commands | results.txt`  ?

Comment: Maybe you'd be interested in using a loop to [execute a command on each file in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523415/execute-command-on-all-files-in-a-directory), or [running a command n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737740/is-there-a-better-way-to-run-a-command-n-times-in-bash) where the number can be used in the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a text editor of your choice and paste the three commands below each other.  Save that file and open a terminal window.  Change to the folder containing the file you just created and run "chmod +x your_file_name_with_python_code_in_it".

Then run that file in the terminal "./your_file_name_with_python_code_in_it >> results.txt"

The >> will create and append to the log file what your python code feeds back to the console.

Comment: I ran your suggestion at the command line and it is giving me syntax error here:

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax
File "dna.py", line 32
dna_sequences = open(f"{sys.argv[1]}", "r").readline().strip()`

My code seems correct and runs in the IDE with no errors

Comment: Did you save the "your_file_name_with_python_code_in_it" file in the same folder as "dna.py"? If not, it should be as I see you use relative path names to databases and sequences folders.

Comment: yes it is in the same folder.  For some reason it does not like this line:

`f"{argv[1]}", "r").readline().strip()`

However the program works in the ide when running each of those commands individually at the command line

Comment: This worked when I changed the command from "python" to "python3" in the text file

Answer (score 1):

you can iterate over sequences generated on the shell `seq`

```
repeat=10
for n in $(seq 1 $repeat);  do python dna.py databases/small.csv sequences/${n}.txt; done
```

as per Jetchisel suggestion, you can brace expansion which is a bash4 feature, that was added in 2009.

```
python dna.py databases/small.csv sequences/{1..3}.txt >> results.txt
```

With the bash c-style for-loop

```
start=1 end=3
for ((n=start;n<=end;n++)); do python dna.py database/small.csv sequences/"$n".txt
```

this would block your terminal until your process finished and would be considered a foreground process with no user interaction. The point here being whether the process blocks the execution of other processes until it terminates.

you can make a foreground process into a background one by adding `&` at the end of your command line.

Comment: `bash` has brace expansion, and can do repeated tasks without `seq` why use it?

Comment: @Jetchisel as far as i know, using direct expansion line `python dna.py databases/small.csv sequences/{1..3}.txt` will return `ambiguous redirect` am I right?

Comment: i have tried `python3 watevver.py >> txt.{1..3}.py`, and it returns `ambiguous redirect`