# Fill file using for loop in bash script

Tags: bash, for-loop

I am trying to write a bash script which will fill a file in a for loop, such that if I run the script with argument 3 it will create the file with 3 lines.

This is the script that I came up with. But it creates the file with only one line.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $1
do
cat > $PWD/http_file$1.csv <<EOF
host_$i,8080,app_$i,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
EOF
cat $PWD/http_file$1.csv
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for i in 3`: bash sees this as looping over all space-delimited options after `in`. In this case, there is only one element, so the loop only runs once.

You can generate a list of numbers via `seq`:

```sh
echo $(seq 1 3)
> 1 2 3
```

TL;DR: Use `for i in $(seq 1 $1)`

Comment: Alternatively you could use this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/3737773/807865 which uses the expansion `{1..$i}` - unfortunately they both break if you pass a zero argument. If this is important, you'll want to add a special check for 0.

Comment: Sorry - "break" may have been the wrong phrasing. The both produce the sequence `1 0` which gives two elements. The expected result would be that no lines are output but you would instead get two lines.

Comment: Ahh - I just tried using a different version of `seq` which actually does not iterate backwards... this may be an implementation detail that varies.

Comment: TIL that does seems to be the case - the behavior of `seq` is non-standard and may vary. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64861/how-to-display-numbers-in-reverse-order-using-seq1

Comment: @andyvanee, the specific thing I intended you to try was `{1..$i}`, which does not expand to a sequence.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, my default shell is `zsh` and I didn't double check it i bash.

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
for ((i=1; i<=$1; i++))
do
    echo "${i}"
done
```

This generates:

```
1
2
3
```