# executing variable substitution/String manipultion N times

Tags: bash

[Repeating same command n times. Question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737740/is-there-a-better-way-to-run-a-command-n-times-in-bash)

But methods in that question are not working for variable assignments

Eg.

```
var='abc,xyz,mnx,duid'
for f in `seq 3`; do var=${var%,*}; done
```

Above works but using it in function as described in other question does't work

Eg.

```
repeat() { num="$"; shift; for f in $(seq $num); do $1; done; }
repeat 3 'var=${var%,*}'
repeat 3 "var=${var%,*}"
```

Doesn't work

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output. It's OK to provide a link to some previous question for reference but we shouldn't NEED to visit that reference for your question to make sense stand-alone. As written we don't know what output you expect, nor what output you got that you didn't expect, nor what you mean by "not working".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variable expansions and assignments aren't processed after expanding variables. You need to use `eval` to re-execute it as a shell command.

You also have a typo, `"$"` should be `"$1"`.

```
repeat() { num="$1"; shift; for f in $(seq $num); do eval "$1"; done; }
repeat 3 'var=${var%,*}'
echo "$var" # output = abc
```

Note that the argument needs to be in single quotes, otherwise the variable expansion will be processed once before calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample data

> ```sh
> var='abc,xyz,mnx,duid'
> ```

you can also have the same effect by concatenating the search terms multiple times

```sh
var=${var%,*,*,*}
```

That said, you could also do things like

```sh
var=${var%$(printf ',*%.0s' {1..3})}
```

or

```sh
n=3; var=${var%$(printf ',*%.0s' $(seq $n))}
```